# Can I override device capabilities properties of AWS Device Farm?

Tags: aws-device-farm

Can I override device capabilities properties of AWS Device Farm? Like default Device capabilities start android test with Splash Activity, how can I override such capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

I work for AWS Device Farm. If you are using Appium 1.4.16, you will not be able to override any capabilities because Appium is pre-launched.

If you are using Appium 1.6.3 or 1.6.5, you can override the capabilities using desired capabilities in your tests.

However, Device Farm prevents customers from overriding certain capabilities: 'app', 'udid', 'platform-name', 'platform-version', 'automation-name', 'tmp', 'webdriveragent-url', 'browser-name'